# Trying to RVM install Ruby 2.4.1 for Mac El Capitan 10.11.6 and getting

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I've looked around to a few different similar problems, and ended up imploding RVM and starting from scratch a few times, and am still getting the same error. rvm version is 1.29.2

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/bsturms/.rvm/log/1503424267_ruby-2.4.1/make.log
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
compiling dmyenc.c
linking miniruby
config.status: creating ruby-runner.h
generating encdb.h
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Users/bsturms/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.1/./miniruby (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Users/bsturms/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.1/./miniruby (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [encdb.h] Trace/BPT trap: 5
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```